# IntelliJ doesn’t save code changes before running tests

Tags: unit-testing, intellij-idea

In my Run test using set in **IntelliJ IDEA**, IntelliJ doesn’t save code changes before running tests.

[My Run tests using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysLsC.png)

This is my [error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Pllt.png). I deleted carStatusEventhandlerWebClient bean. But When I running test using Intellij IDEA, the bean still alive.

So, I tried using gradle. then the test code works well.

The test code is below

```
@SpringBootTest
class Test {

    @Test
    fun tt() {
        val p = ReserveCarRentalV2Params(
            handleReward = GetHandleRewardResult(Reward(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)),
            conditionReward = 1,
            carId = 1,
            zoneId = "1",
            handleTime = 1L
        )

        println(p)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @CrazyCoder sorry. provide my test code for you. thanks